# How to write query to find firebase event details in last 28days using bigquery with platform, steam_id, event_name filter in power bi?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

firebase console and its first_open output

[image]

**Firebase.console Result**   first_open 8,787- 8,575 -

I'm trying to create a query to get the event details using the big query but not it produces an exact result

My Query is

```
select platform, count(s.platform) from (SELECT * FROM `Table.events_*` where event_name = "first_open" and stream_id = "1757261196" or stream_id = "1759866139"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `Table.events_intraday_*` where event_name = "first_open" and stream_id = "1757261196" or stream_id = "1759866139" ) s where and event_date between "20191204" and "20200101" group by s.platform
```

My filter is

```
Stream_id = ["1757261196","1759866139"]
platform = ["ios","android"]
dateRanges = last 28days
event_name = first_open
```

**BigQuery Result:**

```
[
  {
    "platform": "ANDROID",
    "f0_": "428"
  },
  {
    "platform": "IOS",
    "f0_": "38"
  }
]
```

But firebase console output and bigquery output are different I think it is due to query issue, please help me to write the correct query.

Comment: This question doesn't seem related to the Firebase Realtime Database, so please don't tag it as such. Time we spend on retagging is time that we can't use to help in other ways.

Comment: Could you please specify which output is from Firebase and which is from Bigquery? I am guessing that the first one is from Firebase, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Yes you are correct the first one is firebase.console and second one is the big query result @S.Tyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has some missing pieces at the `WHERE` statement. So I'm not even sure if that QUERY that you shared with us works.

From what I could observe from the QUERY your `WHERE` statement has some issues with the precedence of the `AND`, `OR` operators.

What you have is:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE event_name = "first_open" AND stream_id = "1757261196" OR stream_id = "1759866139"
```

This is returning two sets:

- One with the `event_name="first_open"`, and the `stream_id = "1757261196"`
- A second one, with the `stream_id="1759866139"`

This means that the first condition is not being applied correctly.

I recommend you to use the following structure:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE event_name = "first_open" AND (stream_id = "1757261196" OR stream_id = "1759866139")
```

This way you put together the conditionals of the `stream_id` which are the only ones that should be affected by the `OR` operator, and the first conditional is always applied.

After this take a good look at the final `WHERE`:

```
...) s where and event_date between "20191204" and "20200101" group by s.platform
```

This may not be working as you are expecting because of the data type of that column, and how you are passing the data to the `BETWEEN`. Be sure is a DATE type and is in the same format, you can always cast the values with `DATE()` if is something else.

**EDIT:**

> After you link a project to BigQuery, the first daily export of events
>   creates a corresponding dataset in the associated BigQuery project.
>   Then, each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a new
>   daily table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is streamed
>   into a separate intraday BigQuery table in real-time. Data prior to
>   linking to BigQuery is not available for import (except for
>   Performance Monitoring data). By default, all web data from your App +
>   Web properties in Google Analytics will be exported as well.

[Source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en)

The query seems to be OK, there is only one more consideration to make:

- Be careful when you use wildcards `Table.events_*` includes `Table.events_intraday_*`, if they are in the same Dataset in BigQuery. This could lead to duplicated data in your query and will cause a mismatch in your counts.

Besides that, I recommend you to follow the next steps, with the idea that the issue is not the query:

- Verify that the tables for every single day that you are querying exist in BigQuery. The smaller count seems to be from a single day vs the bigger amount.
- Validate that the tables from BigQuery contain the same data as the "Events" dataset from Firebase, you could be comparing two different datasets and hence the numbers will never match.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still count mismatch is there, I don't know the reason.@S.Tyr

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A take a look at the update (EDIT) in the answer, it seems like you have just created the link from Firebase to BigQuery, and you have only a few days data in your BigQuery tables. I also added some additional considerations when you found yourself in this kind of scenario.